# node error when calling "yarn start" in an app created by create-react-app

Tags: node.js, create-react-app, antd

I recently created a new project with create-react-app, installed all newest packages for an old create-react-app project (which was using react-scripts 3.4.1, and the new project is using 5.0.0) and copied the old code and asset files over. To my puzzlement, the new project throws an error whenever I call "yarn start"

```
Starting the development server...

node:events:498
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: read ECONNRESET
    at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:217:20)
Emitted 'error' event on ClientRequest instance at:
    at TLSSocket.socketErrorListener (node:_http_client:442:9)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at emitErrorNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:164:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (node:internal/streams/destroy:129:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21) {
  errno: -54,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Node.js v17.4.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

For what it's worth, the old project doesn't throw an error despite that the src code is the same. The only difference is the packages.

I googled around and followed various advice, including this one: https://medium.com/@premal.katigar/how-to-fix-throw-er-unhandled-error-event-30172323a973. All to no avail.

There are a couple of clues that could be useful:

1. I use an antd landing page, which is basically a bunch of .jsx and .less files that constructs a page. If I replace that landing page code with some simple jsx component, e.g. something that simply returns an h1 tag, then there is no longer this node error. Yarn start would start the project fine.
2. The only differences between the old project that starts fine even with the aforementioned antd landing page, and the new one that throws the above error are that 1) the new project contains all the newest versions of the required packages, since I used "yarn install" for all the required packages 2) since I'm using the newest version of antd, instead of using "customize-cra", "react-app-wired", "babel-plugin-import" and "less-loader", I was simply using "craco-less". So the old project's "yarn start" actually called "react-app-rewired start" and the new one actually called "craco start".

I also tried downgrading node version from 17 to 16, and the error remained.

Any clue what might be the issue?

Comment: use this version: 15.2.1. https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/35824

Comment: thanks @Yilmaz. The link you sent seems to be describing a bug of node 14. I'm using node 16.13.2 and 17.4.0 -- shouldn't the same bug be absent, since node 15.2.1 already fixed that?